# How do I convert Firebase Dictionary to class in C#

Tags: c#, firebase, list, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving a list of users from Firebase but they are coming in as KVP.

```
{[FirstName, Eric]}
{[LastNae, EricLastName]}
{[Email, Eric@yahoo.com]}
{[Phone, 12345]}
```

I need to convert this list of KVP to a list of Object Type named Person Class

```
Person
{
string FirstName {get; set;}
string LastName {get; set;}
string Email {get; set;}
string Phone {get; set;}
}
```

What is the most quick and efficient way of doing so:

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the rest of your backend is architected but you can try something like using LINQ to create a new Person object for each KVP you obtained from Firebase.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class FirebaseConverter
{
    public List<Person> ConvertToPersonList(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> firebaseData)
    {
        return firebaseData
            .GroupBy(kv => kv.Key)
            .Select(group => new Person
            {
                FirstName = GetValueByKey(group, "FirstName"),
                LastName = GetValueByKey(group, "LastName"),
                Email = GetValueByKey(group, "Email"),
                Phone = GetValueByKey(group, "Phone"),
            })
            .ToList();
    }

    private string GetValueByKey(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> group, string key)
    {
        return group.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key == key).Value;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use LINQ though, you can store all the KVPs in a list and iterate through them, and then map the key-value pairs to the properties of the Person class. I would personally choose LINQ implementation though as it makes the code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the one below would work as well. This includes iterating through your dictionary and assigning values to `Person` object.

```
                // Assume you have key value pair dictionary  as below
                Dictionary<string, string> firebaseDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "FirstName", "Eric" },
                    { "LastName", "EricLastName" },
                    { "Email", "Eric@yahoo.com" },
                    { "Phone", "12345" }
                };
        
                // You can convert the Firebase dictionary to a list of Person objects
    
                List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
                foreach (var kvp in firebaseDict)
                {
                    Person person = new Person();
                        if (kvp.Key == "FirstName")
                        {
                            person.FirstName = kvp.Value;
                        }
                        else if (kvp.Key == "LastName")
                        {
                            person.LastName = kvp.Value;
                        }
                        else if (kvp.Key == "Email")
                        {
                            person.Email = kvp.Value;
                        }
                        else if (kvp.Key == "Phone")
                        {
                            person.Phone = kvp.Value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Handle unexpected keys or ignore them
                        }
                    people.Add(person);
                }
```

Comment: There is an issue with this. It is adding a new person for every switch case. because new Person is created on every loop and then added to the Person List on every switch.

 They need to all be in one Person Object.

Comment: You can replace the switch with nested if and else if statement if necessasry. refer the updated answer